# How to assign an array value to an object using JOLT?

Tags: arrays, jolt

I'm trying to flatten a json file and convert array elements to objects and assign those object values from another array. I will post both desired output and my current spec in a response:

Here's my input (required output in response):

````
{
  "information": {
    "Id": "2",
    "cId": "P2",
    "sId": 11,
 "dataFrom": "4/15/2018T6:31:02Z",
 "dataTo": "4/15/2018T6:42:02Z"
},
"description": {
 "indicator": "SomeName",
 "details": {
   "headers": [
     "id",
     "aId",
     "NAME4"
   ],
   "values": [
     [
       1609,
       12,
       "NAME3"
     ],
     [
       1610,
       11,
       "NAME2"
     ]
   ]
 }
}
}```
````

Comment: Desired output:
    ``` [{
  "Id": "2",
  "cId": "P2",
  "sId": 11,
  "dataFrom": "4/15/2018T6:31:02Z",
  "dataTo": "4/15/2018T6:42:02Z"
  "indicator": "SomeName"
  "id":1609
  "aId": 12
  "NAME4:"NAME3"
 }, {
  "Id": "2",
  "cId": "P2",
  "sId": 11,
  "dataFrom": "4/15/2018T6:31:02Z",
  "dataTo": "4/15/2018T6:42:02Z"
  "indicator": "SomeName"
  "id":1610
  "aId": 11
  "NAME4:"NAME2"
 }]```
 
 
]
   ```

Comment: Current spec:
    ```[

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "information": {
        "*": "&0"
      },
      "description": {
        "indicator": "&0",
        "details": {
          "headers": { //"&0"
            "*": {
              "*": "&0"
                //"$0": ""
            }
          },
          "values": { //"&0"
            "*": {
              "*": "&0"
                //"$0": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

 ]```